# How to htaccess redirect 301 from old to new site with conditions

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

Is it possible at the same time to

- redirect 301 multiple URLs/pages from old to new
- redirect 301 all remain old pages to new homepage
- redirect 301 both www/without of old homepage to new homepage
- exclude one URL

URLs don't match (meaning each old site URL is redirected to a different URL at the new site.

Comment: Are the old and new sites hosted in the same webspace, or are they entirely separate?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^oldsite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?unchanged/url - [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/?specific/page) http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newsite.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The order is the important part. First, handle the URL which you don't want to apply the rules to. The [L] flag should stop processing further rules. Then, handle your other specific URLs. After that, redirect the other URLs.

Comment: Since this is intended to be in .htaccess, the `RewriteRule` pattern shouldn't start with a slash. In the first `RewriteRule`, you can simply use a `-` (hyphen) for the _substitution_ to indicate no change (is the `HTTP_HOST` check required here? Or should it be reversed? I assume it is intended to go on the _old_ site?).

Comment: Thanks. Those are some great tips. I was assuming that for the unchanged URL, I would need a `HTTP_HOST` because I couldn't specify that in the rule itself, and perhaps he only wants the one URL unchanged. I suppose that I'm also assuming that both are sharing the same document root.